# Allow Django custom field to trigger save() on parent model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

### Problem:

I have a custom field type that occasionally needs to update its attributes and re-save itself to database.  I'm trying to determine if I can enforce this at the field layer without implementing at the model layer.

### Motivation:

I checked out how django.contrib.auth [handles workfactor upgrades](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f5e9d67907510881c7f132d0a80e39f47caea5f6/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L105), and it relegates this task to the model that owns the encrypted field.

I'd prefer to implement this at the field level so that the custom field type can be implemented on many models across various apps.

### Example:

I have a custom field type, `SecretField`, which stores type `Secret` as a model attribute.  Normally, a `Secret` contains encrypted data, and the key is a PBKDF2 hash of a user-provided password.  Decryption occurs on an as-needed basis.

Let's say this is implemented with the below outline:

```
from django.utils.six import with_metaclass
from django.db import models

class BuriedTreasure(models.Model):
    location = SecretField()

class SecretField(with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.Field)):
    #... (a bunch of logic) ...

class Secret(object):
    def __init__(self, ciphertext, salt, workfactor):
        self.ciphertext = ciphertext
        self.salt = salt
        self.workfactor = workfactor

    @classmethod
    def from_ciphertext(cls, ciphertext, salt, workfactor):
        """Generate a Secret object for later decyption."""
        return cls(ciphertext, salt, workfactor)

    def to_plaintext(self, password):
        """Decrypt ciphertext and return plaintext."""
        #... (decrypt ciphertext using salt & workfactor) ...
        return plaintext

bt = BuriedTreasure.objects.get(pk=1)
print bt.location.to_plaintext('mypassword')
```

When `bt.location.to_plaintext()` is called, I would like to check if `bt.location.workfactor` no longer meet's Django requirements (which may have changed due to a Django upgrade).  If not, I should re-encrypt the `Secret` and issue  `bt.save(update_fields=['location'])` to upgrade the secret's protection. This solution would allow all `SecretField` attributes to automatically upgrade their workfactors upon decryption.

### What I'd like to implement:

I'd like to implement this via something like:

```
class Secret(object):
    def __init__(self, ciphertext, salt, workfactor, plaintext=None, password=None):
        self.ciphertext = ciphertext
        self.salt = salt
        self.workfactor = workfactor
        #...

    @classmethod
    def from_ciphertext(cls, ciphertext, salt, workfactor):
        """Generate a Secret object for later decyption."""
        return cls(ciphertext, salt, workfactor)

    def from_plaintext(cls, plaintext, password):
        """Generate a Secret object from plaintext and password."""
        return cls(plaintext=plaintext, password=password)

    def to_plaintext(self, password):
        """Decrypt ciphertext and return plaintext."""
        #... (decrypt ciphertext using salt & workfactor) ...

        if self.workfactor < DJANGO_THRESHOLD:
            new_secret = Secret.from_plaintext(plaintext, password)
            #Update parent model's field with new_secret
            #Save parent model's field to database
        return plaintext
```

### Where I'm stuck

Presently, I can't figure out how to access the model instance to which the `Secret` belongs. Even if I register the `SecretField` with the `Secret` instance from within `SecretField.from_db_value()`, I can't find a way to access the parent model.  Is this possible, or is there a better way to accomplish my goal (perhaps via implementing on a generic, inheritable model)?

Comment: Simply put: you're just wasting your time. What is wrong with a model's `save` method? Whenever a field changes call the `save` method of the model and the changed field will be updated.

Comment: xyres - valid question. I'd like to make this custom field portable, so it can be used by other projects, and I don't want to rely on each project to implement its own `Secret` maintenance process.  If I can bake this feature into the field type, it would ensure this maintenance is implemented everywhere the field type is used.